# Fabric 2 automating deployment error when git pulling on remote server. Repository not found

Tags: python, git, paramiko, fabric, invoke-command

I'm trying to automate my deployment with Fabric 2.

When I manually do a git pull through the command line on the remote server everything works fine.

When I try to do the same with my Fabric/Invoke script it does not allow me to pull.

It does though allow me to do git status and other commands.

### The code:

```
# Imports
from fabric import Connection
from fabric.tasks import task
import os

# Here i pass my local passphrase:
kwargs = {'passphrase': os.environ["SSH_PASSPHRASE"]}

@task
def serverdeploy(c, branch="Staging"):
    con = Connection('myuser@myhost', connect_kwargs=kwargs)
    with con.cd("/home/user/repository/"):
        # Activate the virtual environment:
        with con.prefix("source ENV/bin/activate"):
            con.run("git pull origin {}".format(branch))
```

The results are:

```
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

### Notes:

I don't even get asked for a passphrase while doing the pull.

I have tried doing the pull without activating the environment but that didn't work either.

---

What could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please place `con.run("git pull origin {}".format(branch))` outside the `with con.prefix("source ENV/bin/activate"):`.

Your code has nothing to do with the interpreter or the virtual env! Try that and it should works!

Comment: Thank you, that was step one. Step two was adding pty=True on the git command

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that the user that you log in as has the proper ssh key setup for bitbucket.org, but the fabric connection user is different.  You can test whether the setup is correct by using these two commands as the user that fabric connects as:

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
ssh -T -i /path/to/private_key git@bitbucket.org
```

In order to fix this issue, copy the private key to the `/home/myuser/.ssh` directory and add an ssh config entry for bitbucket.org to `/home/myuser/.ssh/config`:

```
Host bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile /path/to/private_key
```